# Glassfish webservice high concurrency

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-3, jmeter

When I send about 100 users to my web service, I get response and web service performs fine, but when I check for 1000 concurrent users none of the requests get reply.

I am using jmeter for testing.

When I send 1000 concurrent users my glassfish admin panel goes time out in browser and it opens after 4-5 minutes only.Same happen for wsdl URL.

I have tested my web service on our LAN and it works for 2000 queries without any issues.

Please help me find a solution.

**Edit 1.0**

Some more findings

Hi on your recommendation, what I did is that I simply returned string on web service function call, no lookup, no dao, nothing... just returning a string

Thread pool is 2000 no issues on that.

Now when I ran jmeter for 1000 users they run much fast and returned response for ~200 requests

So this means that my PC running Windows 7 with an i5 processor and 4GB RAM is out performing dedicated server of hostgator having 4GB RAM with xeon 5*** 8 cores :(

This is not for what am paying 220$ a month....

Correct me if my finding is wrong, I tested my app on lan b/w two pc's locally and it can process 2000+msgs smoothly

**Edit 1.1**

After lot of reading,and practicals I have come to a conclusion that it is network latency which is responsible for such a behavior.

I increased bean pool size in glassfish's admin panel and it helped improving number of concurrent users to 300, but issue arise again no matter how much beans I keep in pool.

So friends question is: please suggest some other settings which I can change in Glassfish's admin panel to remove this issue from root!

Comment: Q: Have you checked the OS error logs when this occurs?  What *is* the server OS, anyway?  Q: What about the database logs?  What's the database?  Do you see a spike in locks/deadlocks?  Etc etc - you definitely need to do some more homework to determine where the bottleneck is occurring.

Comment: Please check Edit 1.1,OS has no issue,because php site is also hosted on same box with fairly high concurrency tested for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some performance logging for the various steps that your service performs. Does it do multiple steps? Is computation slow? Database access slow? Your connection pool not scale well? Do things need to be tweaked in the web server to allow for such high concurrency? You'll need to measure these things to find the bottlenecks so you can eliminate them.

Comment: Hi on your recomendation, what i did is that i simply returned string on webservice function call,no lookup,no dao,nothing...just lame return String

Thread pool is 2000 no issues on that.

Now when i ran jmeter for 1000 users they run much fast and returned response for ~200 requests

so this means that my PC running windows 7 having i5 4GB RAM is out performing dedicated server of hostgator having 4GB RAM with xeon 5*** 8 cores :(
this is not for what am paying 220$ a month....
Correct me if my finding is wrong,i test my app on lan b/w two pc's locally and it can process 2000+msgs smoothly

Comment: Are you trying to compare the performance of running on a lan v.s. over the internet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a server (with 200+ simultaneously users), I studied the official glassfish tuning guide but there is a parameter very important that doesn't appear. I used Jmeter too and in my case the time response increases exponentially but the server's processor stay low.

In the glassfish admin server (configurations/server-config/Network config/thread pools/http-thread-pool) you can see how many users you server can handle. (The parameters are different in glassfish 2 and 3).

> Max Queue Size: The maximum number of threads in the queue. A value of –1 indicates that there is no limit to the queue size.
>
> Max Thread Pool Size: The maximum number of threads in the thread pool
>
> Min Thread Pool Size: The minimum number of threads in the thread pool
>
> Idle Thread Timeout: The maximum amount of time that a thread can remain idle in the pool. After this time expires, the thread is removed from the pool.

I recommend you to set **Max Thread Pool Size** to 100 or 200 to fix the problem.

Also you can set another JMV variables, for example:

> -Xmx/s/m
>
> -server
>
> -XX:ParallelGCThreads
>
> -XX:+AggressiveOpts

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi javier i went ahead and did jvm tunning....but unfortunately i cant exceed more than 100 concurrent users....if i exceed users i get cant open socket exception for all queries in Jmeter